# Extract data out of JSON and put into HTML LI

Tags: json

I would like to extract data out of my JSON file but it doesn't work and I do not know what I am doing wrong. I am forgetting something?

The extracted data need to be put into a li

My script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
   var checky = [];
   $.getJSON('checky.json', function(data) {
       $.each(data.checky, function() {
          var bars = "<li style='height:" + times + "'>" + day + "</li>"
           $(bars).appendTo("#graph");
     });
   });
});
</script>
```

My HTML:

```
<ul class="barGraph" id="graph">
```

My JSON:

```
{
   "checky": [
       {
           "day": "1",
           "times": 25
       },,
       {
           "day": "2",
           "times": 18
       },,
       {
           "day": "3",
           "times": 10
       },,
       {
           "day": "4",
           "times": 19
       },,
       {
           "day": "5",
           "times": 30
       },,
       {
           "day": "6",
           "times": 18
       },
       {
           "day": "7",
           "times": 78
       },
       {
           "day": "8",
           "times": 35
       },
       {
           "day": "9",
           "times": 26
       },
       {
           "day": "11",
           "times": 18
       },
       {
           "day": "12",
           "times": 5
       },
       {
           "day": "13",
           "times": 10
       },
       {
           "day": "14",
           "times": 14
       },
       {
           "day": "15",
           "times": 29
       },
       {
           "day": "16",
           "times": 61
       },
       {
           "day": "17",
           "times": 25
       },
       {
           "day": "18",
           "times": 18
       },
       {
           "day": "19",
           "times": 11
       },
       {
           "day": "20",
           "times": 67
       },
       {
           "day": "21",
           "times": 92
       },
       {
           "day": "22",
           "times": 29
       },
       {
           "day": "23",
           "times": 39
       },
       {
           "day": "24",
           "times": 24
       },
       {
           "day": "25",
           "times": 79
       },
       {
           "day": "26",
           "times": 28
       },
       {
           "day": "27",
           "times": 48
       },
       {
           "day": "28",
           "times": 28
       },
       {
           "day": "29",
           "times": 29
       },
       {
           "day": "30",
           "times": 84
       },
       {
           "day": "31",
           "times": 148
       }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of separate issues with your current code and data.

1. There are indexes in your array with `undefined` value. (two commas with no value between them: ...`},,{`...
   Replace these with a single comma at every occurrence to fix these basic issues with your data. *(alternately add some logic in your loop to skip these if you don't have easy control over your data source).*
2. `$.each` doesn't work the way it looks like you think it does. The first parameter to the callback function is the index of the array, and second is the value from that index. Access your `times` and `day` properties through the second parameter.
3. You're passing a regular string to the `$.fn.appendTo` function - this should be a jQuery object instead: `$(bars).appendTo($("#graph"));`

---

simple fixed copy of your code using the tips above: (note - you need to fix point 1 above as well as use the below)

```
$.each(data.checky, function(index, item) {
    var bars = "<li style='height:" + item.times + "px'>" + item.day + "</li>"
    $graph.append($('#graph'));
});
```

---

For better performance and best practices, I have a few extra tips:

- Don't make new jQuery objects in your loop.
- Concatenate all your html into a single variable then do one DOM operation to insert it all at once.
- Use double quotes for html attribute values instead of single quotes.

Example:

```
var html = '';
$.each(data.checky, function(index, item) {
    html += '<li style="height: '+item.times+'px;">'+item.day+'</li>';
});
$('#graph').append(html);
```

Comment: First of all thanks for taking your time to solve this issue for me and pointing out the things I did wrong. Also thank you for giving me tips in how to improve my way of coding! You made my day!

Comment: You're welcome :) Glad to help, and thanks for the positive feedback on the answer as well :)