# Populating list items with JSON data

Tags: javascript, html, api

I need help converting JSON data from an API into items in an unordered list, such that each segment is a separate item. I plan on using if, elseIf, and else statements to set the icons. I have a script to set the time but I'm not sure how to convert each segment into a li which is what I need help with.

How do I convert this:

```
segments: Array(5)
 0:
  bounds: {maximum: {…}, minimum: {…}}
  from: {origin: {…}}
  times: {start: "2021-04-20T14:25:00", end: "2021-04-20T14:28:00", durations: {…}}
  to: {stop: {…}}
  type: "walk"
  __proto__: Object
 1:
  bounds: {maximum: {…}, minimum: {…}}
  bus: {bike-rack: "false", easy-access: "true", wifi: "false"}
  route: {key: 662, number: 662, name: "Route 662 Richmond", customer-type: "regular", coverage: "feeder", …}
  times: {start: "2021-04-20T14:28:00", end: "2021-04-20T14:40:00", durations: {…}}
  type: "ride"
  variant: {key: "662-0-U", name: "Richmond to University of Manitoba"}
  __proto__: Object
 2:
  bounds: {maximum: {…}, minimum: {…}}
  from: {stop: {…}}
  times: {start: "2021-04-20T14:40:00", end: "2021-04-20T14:59:00", durations: {…}}
  to: {stop: {…}}
  type: "transfer"
  __proto__: Object
 3:
  bounds: {maximum: {…}, minimum: {…}}
  bus: {bike-rack: "false", easy-access: "true", wifi: "false"}
  route: {key: 74, number: 74, name: "Route 74 Kenaston", customer-type: "regular", 
  coverage: "regular", …}
  times: {start: "2021-04-20T14:59:00", end: "2021-04-20T15:24:00", durations: {…}}
  type: "ride"
  variant: {key: "74-1-P", name: "Kenaston to Polo Park"}
  __proto__: Object
 4:
  bounds: {maximum: {…}, minimum: {…}}
  from: {stop: {…}}
  times: {start: "2021-04-20T15:24:00", end: "2021-04-20T15:25:00", durations: {…}}
  to: {destination: {…}}
  type: "walk"
  __proto__: Object

 length: 5
 __proto__: Array(0)
```

into this:

```
<div class="bus-container">
    <ul class="my-trip">
      <li><span class="material-icons">exit_to_app</span> Depart at 9:55:00 AM.</li>
      <li><span class="material-icons">directions_walk</span>Walk for 6 minutes to stop #50577 - Northbound St Mary's at
        Avalon</li>
      <li><span class="material-icons">directions_bus</span>Ride the Route 14 Ellice-St. Mary's for 23 minutes.</li>
      <li><span class="material-icons">transfer_within_a_station</span>Transfer from stop #10643 - Northbound Fort at
        Graham to stop #10611 - Eastbound Graham at Fort (Wpg Square)</li>
      <li><span class="material-icons">directions_bus</span>Ride the Route 16 Selkirk-Osborne for 16 minutes.</li>
      <li><span class="material-icons">transfer_within_a_station</span>Transfer from stop #30296 - Westbound Selkirk at
        Arlington to stop #30295 - Northbound Arlington at Selkirk</li>
      <li><span class="material-icons">directions_bus</span>Ride the Route 71 Arlington for 13 minutes.</li>
      <li><span class="material-icons">directions_walk</span>Walk for 3 minutes to your destination, arriving at
        11:00:00 AM</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

This is my entire code

```
let mapboxApiKey = "pk.eyJ1IjoibmFuZGluaS1hIiwiYSI6ImNrbW1iN2xqdjFqYmYycG80bmo2bDYwN24ifQ.GQN5FI2XaZYpt8KKxYcMQQ";
let transitApiKey = "p7qbH-VgW-2M5BRlkbwv";
let originForm = document.querySelector(".origin-form");
let originInput = document.querySelector(".origin-form input");
let destinationForm = document.querySelector(".destination-form");
let destinationInput = document.querySelector(".destination-form input");
let origins = document.querySelector(".origins");
let destinations = document.querySelector(".destinations");
let planTripBtn = document.querySelector(".plan-trip");
let myTrip = document.querySelector(".my-trip");
let originLong;
let originLat;
let destinationLong;
let destingationLat;
origins.innerHTML = "";
destinations.innerHTML = "";
myTrip.innerHTML = "";

originForm.onsubmit = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (originInput.value.length > 0) {
    getOriginLocations(originInput.value);
  }
}

originForm.onclick = function () {
  if (originInput.value.length > 0) {
    origins.innerHTML = "";
    originInput.value = "";
  }
}

destinationForm.onsubmit = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (destinationInput.value.length > 0) {
    getDestinationLocations(destinationInput.value);
  }
}

destinationForm.onclick = function () {
  if (originInput.value.length > 0) {
    destinations.innerHTML = "";
    destinationInput.value = "";
  }
}

planTripBtn.onclick = function () {
  if (originLong !== null && originLat !== null && destinationLong !== null && destingationLat !== null) {
    getRoute(originLong, originLat, destinationLong, destinationLat);
  }
}

async function getOriginLocations(searchedOrigin) {
  const originResponse = await fetch(`https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/${searchedOrigin}.json?bbox=-97.325875,49.766204,-96.953987,49.99275&access_token=${mapboxApiKey}`);
  const originData = await originResponse.json();
  originData.features.forEach(originLocation => {
    let originPlaceNameData = originLocation.place_name.split(", ");
    let originLocationName = originPlaceNameData[0];
    let originLocationAddress = originPlaceNameData[1];

    origins.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", `
      <li data-long="${originLocation.geometry.coordinates[0]}" data-lat="${originLocation.geometry.coordinates[1]}">
      <div class="name">${originLocationName}</div>
      <div>${originLocationAddress}</div>
      </li>
    `);
  });

  origins.onclick = e => {
    let originElement = e.target.closest('li');
    if (originElement !== null) {
      originElement.className = "selected";
      originLong = originElement.dataset.long;
      originLat = originElement.dataset.lat;
    }
  }
}

async function getDestinationLocations(searchedDestination) {
  const destinationResponse = await fetch(`https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/${searchedDestination}.json?bbox=-97.325875,49.766204,-96.953987,49.99275&access_token=${mapboxApiKey}`);
  const destinationData = await destinationResponse.json();
  destinationData.features.forEach(destinationLocation => {
    let destinationPlaceNameData = destinationLocation.place_name.split(", ");
    let destinationLocationName = destinationPlaceNameData[0];
    let destinationLocationAddress = destinationPlaceNameData[1];

    destinations.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", `
    <li data-long="${destinationLocation.geometry.coordinates[0]}" data-lat="${destinationLocation.geometry.coordinates[1]}">
    <div class="name">${destinationLocationName}</div>
    <div>${destinationLocationAddress}</div>
  </li>
    `);
  });

  destinations.onclick = e => {
    let destinationElement = e.target.closest('li');
    if (destinationElement !== null) {
      destinationElement.className = "selected";
      destinationLong = destinationElement.dataset.long;
      destinationLat = destinationElement.dataset.lat;
    }
  }
}

async function getRoute(originLong, originLat, destinationLong, destinationLat) {
  const routeResponse = await fetch(`https://api.winnipegtransit.com/v2/trip-planner.json?api-key=${transitApiKey}&origin=geo/${originLat},${originLong}&destination=geo/${destinationLat},${destinationLong}`);
  const routeData = await routeResponse.json();
  let hourArray = [];
  let minutesArray = [];
  let durationsArray = [];
  let minHour;
  let minMinutes;
  let minDuration;

  routeData.plans.forEach(route => {
    let date = new Date(route.times.end);
    let hours = date.getHours();
    let minutes;
    if (hours === minHour) {
      minutes = date.getMinutes();
      minutesArray.push(minutes);
    }
    hourArray.push(hours);
  });

  minHour = Math.min(...hourArray);
  console.log(minHour);

  routeData.plans.forEach(route => {
    let date = new Date(route.times.end);
    let hours = date.getHours();
    let minutes;
    if (hours === minHour) {
      minutes = date.getMinutes();
      minutesArray.push(minutes);
    }
  });

  minMinutes = Math.min(...minutesArray);
  console.log(minMinutes);

  routeData.plans.forEach(route => {
    let date = new Date(route.times.end);
    let hours = date.getHours();
    let minutes;
    let durations;
    if (hours === minHour) {
      minutes = date.getMinutes();
      if (minMinutes === minMinutes) {
        durations = route.times.durations.total;
        durationsArray.push(durations);
      }
    }
  });

  minDuration = Math.min(...durationsArray);
  console.log(minDuration);

  routeData.plans.forEach(route => {
    let date = new Date(route.times.end);
    let hours = date.getHours();
    let minutes;
    let durations;
    let getSegmentDuration;
    let icon;
    let stepInfo;

    if (hours === minHour) {
      minutes = date.getMinutes();
      if (minMinutes === minMinutes) {
        durations = route.times.durations.total;
        if (durations === minDuration) {
          let startDate = new Date(route.times.start);
          let startHour = startDate.getHours();
          let startTime;
          let endTime;

          if (startHour <= 12) {
            startTime = `${startHour}:${startDate.getMinutes()}:${startDate.getSeconds()} AM`;
          } else {
            startTime = `${startHour - 12}:${startDate.getMinutes()}:${startDate.getSeconds()} PM`;
          }

          if (hours <= 12) {
            endTime = `${hours}:${date.getMinutes()}:${date.getSeconds()} AM`;
          } else {
            endTime = `${hours - 12}:${date.getMinutes()}:${date.getSeconds()} PM`;
          }

          let myTripText = "";

          //<li><span class="material-icons">exit_to_app</span> Depart at ${startTime}.</li>

          route.segments.forEach(segment => {
            getSegmentDuration = segment.times.durations.total

            if (segment.type === "walk") {
              icon = `<span class="material-icons">directions_walk</span>`;

              if (segment.to.stop !== null) {
                stepInfo = `Walk for ${getSegmentDuration} minutes to stop #${segment.to.stop.key.value} - ${segment.to.stop.name}`
              } else if (segment.to.stop === null && segment.to.destination !== null) {
                stepInfo = `Walk for ${getSegmentDuration} to your destination, arriving at ${endTime}`;
              }

            } else if (segment.type === "ride") {
              icon = `<span class="material-icons">directions_bus</span>`;
              stepInfo = `Ride the ${segment.route.name} for ${getSegmentDuration} minutes`;
            } else if (segment.type === "transfer") {
              icon = `<span class="material-icons">transfer_within_a_station</span>`;
              stepInfo = `Transfer from stop #${segment.from.stop.key} - ${segment.from.stop.name} to stop #${segment.to.stop.key} - ${segment.to.stop.name}`;
            }

              myTripText += `<li>${icon}${stepInfo}<li>`;
          });
          console.log(myTripText);
          myTrip.innerHTML = myTripText;
        }
      }
    }
  });

  // let date = new Date("2021-04-19T20:12:00");
  // let time = date.getHours();
  console.log(routeData);
  // console.log(time);
}
```

(BTW, I'm a beginner so if you all could post simple pieces of code then that would be great! It would also make it much easier for me to understand and implement the code. Thank you!)

**Note: Please refrain from commenting if you're not providing a solution.**

Comment: Also, you're expected to post an attempt, not just your requirements. There's a huge amount of documentation and discussion to be found on operations like this. Give it a try!

Comment: Your desired example should fit to the posted json - but the data seems different...

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in many ways actually depending on your requirements and how you have gone about it. Since I have not been provided with enough information I won't try giving wrong answers. However, I will attach some links that might help you regarding this problem.

[Extract data out of JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27773186/extract-data-out-of-json-and-put-into-html-li)

[For each function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Hope these help. You can find enough working solutions on https://jsfiddle.net/ and https://codepen.io/ ,if looking at working codes helps you understand.